# HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery - Input Range .value() becomes undefined when using jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, scroll

So I'm trying to make a input range object to allow the user to select from a range of values, and reading this and updating a jQuery variable.

If I try to access the value of:

```
<input id="scroll" type="range" min="1" max="60" value="5">
```

If I use:

```
$("#scroll").on("change", function() {
    variable = this.value;
});
```

it functions correct and the variable updates.

However, if I use the jQuery tag selector, as follows:

```
$("#scroll").on("change", function() {
    variable= $("#scroll").value;
}
```

variable becomes undefined.

Could you explain why? My thought is that "this" is referring to the HTML object as it is updated, and uses the HTML attribute, but frankly I don't know enough about it.

Comment: Have your tried `var variable=` to define the variable?

Comment: Oh sorry, the variable was defined outside the scope of this function.  I wanted the function to update the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$("#scroll").val()`. You left out the `#` and you used the DOM property instead of the jQuery method.

```
$("#scroll").on("change", function() {
    variable= $("#scroll").val();
}
```

Comment: `this.value` should return same result?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, that result will be the same but as the David has pointed out using `this.value` is working. It's the jQuery method that isn't working due to a missing `#` in the selector.

Comment: @NewToJS This is correct Answer. Probably not much difference in performance, though why call `jQuery()` and `.val()` instead of `this.value`?

Comment: Oops, I had actually typed out the selector properly in my code, but quickly just edited it in browser. It was because I was using .value instead of .val().

So the explanation is that you can't use DOM properties in js? I saw some solutions which used .html to access the DOM properties, I think.

Comment: You can't use DOM properties in jQuery. It has its own functions.

Comment: `.html()` returns a string containing the HTML of the element.

Comment: Pure javascript `value` / jQuery `val()`  -  Pure Javascript `.innerHTML` / jQuery `.html()` If that helps...

Comment: Do you have any tutorial recommendations? I'm using jQuery in mini-applications to try and learn it.

Comment: I learned jQuery from [jQuery Compressed](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B006DI6QJ2/ref=kinw_myk_ro_title)